# How to book a Vueling ticket with different class fares for outbound and return legs?

Tags: tickets, bookings, vueling

I want to book a return ticket on Vueling. The outbound ticket should be in the "basic" class, since I'm not carrying and luggage. But the return ticket should have the "optima" booking class so that I can check-in a bag.

I am getting this message on their website:

[image]

Would it work if I book the tickets separately?

Comment: It's *possible* to book two one-way tickets but it may cost more than a round-trip ticket. Booking different luggage requirements isn't a "trick" either, it's just reality.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas are you saying it is normal to have different luggage requirmenets? so whey they are not allowing me to do so ?

Comment: It's not a "trick." It's just a fact of travel. Unfortunately certain airlines, like Vueling, will not let you book two different luggage requirements at the same time because it's different types of ticket fares. Other airlines will happily let you book, say, economy one way and first class on the return.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot book a ticket with different class fares, as the Vueling website correctly mentions. You indeed can book the same itinerary as two one-way tickets, but that would be more expensive than a return ticket. Therefore the cheapest option is to add luggage to your "Basic" reservation in the "Customise your flight" step of the booking:

[image: vueling extra luggage]

Comment: actually i booked two separate one-way ticket and the price is the same as the rounded ticket, the only more money i paid is the 2.5 euro because i used credit card twoice, while I could've paid just one

Comment: actually i booked two separate one-way ticket and the price is the same as the rounded ticket, the only more money i paid is the 2.5 euro because i used credit card twoice, while I could've paid just one

Comment: @AniaDavid you can add that as your own answer